# .htaccess url rewrite existing directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a problem concerning my .htaccess

I use the following Rewrite Rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([\w]+)$ /index.php?$1

RewriteRule ^/?([\w]+)/?([\w]+)$ /index.php?$1=$2

RewriteRule ^/?([\w]+)/?([\w]+)/?([\w]+)$ /index.php?$1=$2&$3

RewriteRule ^/?([\w]+)/?([\w]+)/?([\w]+)/?([\w]+)$ /index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4
```

So e.g. the URL domain.com/admin/login calls the url domain.com/index.php?admin=login

This functions well, but when I only ask for the url domain.com/admin the server redirects me to `domain.com/admin/?admin` which only shows a white page (I want to get to `domain.com/index.php?admin` )

The problem is, there is a directory on the server called /admin (earlier I used to name this directory /administration but due to a cookie problem I had to rename it to `/admin`)

Is there a way that if I use the url domain.com/admin that I get redirected correctly to `domain.com/index.php?admin`   ? What do I have to change in my `.htaccess` file?

I hope I could explain the problem well, I'm new to .htaccess so I'm not a pro with naming the problem precisely...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn off the directory slash to rewrite the file.

Put the following  line above "RewriteEngine on" directive in your htaccess

```
 DirectorySlash off
```

Then you will be able to rewrite "admin" (without trailing slash) to "index.php" , "admin/" with a slash will open the directory "admin"

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixes the problem! But now the cookie issue came up again: Without setting a path to setcookie() the login script doesn't work at all.
Using a path like '/' lets me login, but when I logout the cookie isn't deleted!?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES. When ignoring files/folders in .htacces you use `RewriteCond`
Its like telling the browser to skip that folder/file.
In your case you put this above your rewrite rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
```

This will ignore the admin folder. You can also use this for files like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(php|txt|docx)
```

The above will skip the files that end with `.php` or `.txt` or `.docx`